# Software to collaboratively build organizational structure of 10 million entities, with diagram

Tags: project-management, collaboration, diagram, knowledge-organization

I need some help for a project to stop Climate Change.

If everything goes well, I will have a lot of activists pouring into an organization shortly. The rate will be too much for central planning, so they will have to self-organize.

In order to prepare for growth, I must show all activists that there is a place for them in the organization. I plan to do that by creating an empty organizational map, a diagram representing reality, with empty spots from the EU level, down to city district level.

The diagram will take the form of a fractal tree, where I am the root node at the "EU level". I will have 5-6 child nodes, an "intermediate level". Each of these will have 5-6 child nodes in turn, the "Country level". (EU has 28 member states + 1-2 hangarounds = 30) Each Country will be divided into five, each subdivision will be further subdivided into five, on and on, reaching ever smaller geographical subdivisions, until we end up at the neighborhood level after roughly 7-9 layers or so (depending on the EU country).

Each geography will have a leader and a set of function officers, and a set of deputies, for a total of 15 people. Each geography leader will have the responsibility of assigning the geography's function officers, as well as adding geography leaders for the subdivisions right under his/her geography. The map will lag a bit after reality, and the only people who gets assigned are people who have stepped up and are already doing the work. Once someone has a de facto position, they get asked for consent and then added to the map. Volunteers will be able to go to this map whenever they are in need of help, and find the go to person for their need.

To put this in technical terms, I will need a diagram software that can handle a shit ton of entities (10-50 Million) without lagging, being shareable and editable by 10k people+.
I run on a shoestring budget, and can't expect a lot of technical competence from the leaders.

The nodes needs to have configurable default names/values (since each EU country is different and have different languages) that you can set in one central place, updating all the nodes. The data needs to be shared between leaders, and publicly visible (not instantly, if it requires a batch job that's fine as well)

I've tested out draw.io, which sadly started lagging after 2 layers.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Showing 50 million entities on a single page, with all entities being editable, is not going to work.

You will need to split by some levels, for instance one page per state or small country.

I would suggest using MediaWiki:

- Each organizational level can edit its information independently from the others
- No lag, everything works within 1 second
- Accessible to non-technical people
- Powerful localization, which is very important for you
- Reorganization is easy

Free MediaWiki hosting is provided by many hosts on the Internet.

At some point you will certainly want to use categories (for instance one category per state). This extension can create graphs of categories: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Graphical_Category_Browser

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to sync pages between languages? Since the input data (contact info + name) is the same, it would be a shame if all the different languages would have to be synched manually.

Comment: Also, do mediawiki support diagrams on a page? I would be nice to be able to show the organizational structure for the geography (including leader, deputies and function officers)

Comment: Yes, localization is quite smart, one edit changes things for all languages. Here is an example: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page Press "View source" and find `<translate><!--T:11--> Core issues and collaboration</translate>`

Comment: The extension I linked to show diagrams for categories. As you probably won't have a category for each deputy, you would probably need to create SVG files (for instance with Inkscape) and upload them to your wiki, then include each one in its relevant article.